# How to put content evenly by vertical in LinearLayout with saving content height size?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to put content items evenly by vertical in LinearLayout on my Android screen, all ok, but their height stretches by layout-weight rules. How to fix it? Here is my screen in xml-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/olumn128"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Olumn"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Login"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put space view between items and set it's weight to 1 and remove current weights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/column128"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Olumn"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="40dp" />

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"        
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Secondly, you can wrap your items with framelayout and set frames weight to 1 and remove your current weights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/column128"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Olumn"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="40dp" />
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ><TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```